# JavaFX how to write text to a new line in a textArea?

Tags: java, string, javafx, append

I use this:
`TextA.appendText(String)` Is there a way to put the text to the next line?

Comment: Do you mean other than using appendText?

Comment: textArea.appendText(string + "\n");

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Or if you want to have it a bit more direct:

```
String newLine = "\n";
```

Append or prepend the new line to your `TextArea` to create new lines.

Comment: I'm on windows and I tries splitting with `\r\n` or `System.lineSeperator()` if you want to be precise. This hasn't worked because TextArea seems to ignore the operating system and just uses `\n` at all times. I haven't seen a confirmation of this in the JavaDoc so I'd like to ask if the TextArea indeed ignores the operating system

Answer (score 1):

TextA.appendText("\n")

Will add a new line.